# What is a term for someone who always rejects other people’s offers or favors?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there any word for someone who doesn't accept others' favors? They have no reason for it, they just say no. Perhaps it's because they would feel insecure.

Example:

-Why does she always say no when I offer her snacks or drinks?

-You know she is a [word]

Comment: Do you mean people who are too polite to accept help?

Comment: @alphabet not necessarily, they just refuse it.

Comment: It's fairly unusual for someone to have *no reason* behind their decision to refuse others' favors.

Comment: @alphabet maybe they feel unsecure? like being looked down upon or being indebted?

Comment: So put that in your question.

Comment: And please provide a sentence where the word would fit.

Comment: Any such word is likely to carry nuances. Would you want to use it with a sense of approval? So maybe something like *self-reliant*? Or do you want something disapproving like *pain in the rear*? Or do you have some third meaning?  Context is (almost always) everything.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about opinions.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum I'm looking for the negative context, like you are complaining about someone being like that, like they're isolating themselves.

Answer (score -1):

The term that might describe someone who habitually rejects offers or favors from others is "**refusenik**."

In the context you're describing, "refusenik" can be applied to someone who consistently says no to offers or favors without any particular reason. It's important to note that while this term can fit, it might carry different connotations based on the listener's familiarity with its historical context.

Another term that could be used, though less specific, is "**declinist**," which simply means someone who frequently declines offers or invitations. However, this term is not commonly used and might not be immediately understood in casual conversation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the examples I could find for these words were all in political or social context rather than being used in casual everyday conversations.

Comment: Would you go for “fiercely independent”?

Comment: @Xanne Is it used in casual conversations? Can I use it like "they're stingy", or "they're narcissistic"?

Comment: @mtl: "refusenik" is a made-up noun, from "to refuse" and the russian-style suffix "-nik", meaning "someone who is/does" whatever it is affixed to.

Comment: "Refusenik" is never used in this sense. The term only refers to people who refuse to follow the requests of others. It cannot be used for people who merely turn down offers. This answer was likely generated by ChatGPT rather than a native English speaker.

I agree with Xanne that "fiercely independent" is the most idiomatic phrase for this.